# Cannot search the entire date using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In my controller, here is the code.

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $items = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(5);
        $response = [
            'pagination' => [
                'total' => $items->total(),
                'per_page' => $items->perPage(),
                'current_page' => $items->currentPage(),
                'last_page' => $items->lastPage(),
                'from' => $items->firstItem(),
                'to' => $items->lastItem()
            ],
            'data' => $items,
        ];

        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

And I think this the reason. But when I get all the data without using pagination. The Pagination has been broken.

Below is the code I've used in Vue.js.

[image]

The search is working.[image]

[image]

[image]

Searching is working in the data wherein in the pagination only. But cannot search the entire data. Even when in not listed in the page.

```
Task 6 - Is in the Page 1 and can be search
Task 7 - Not in the Page 1 but listed in Page 2 but cannot be search.
```

What is missing in the code. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should [edit] your questions to provide a [mcve], showing how you get your paginated data.

Comment: Agreed! We need more info on where and how you request the data.

Comment: I have updated my question adding the requesting data from the controller. Hope it helps to solve my concern. Thanks

Comment: Or can I create a function in computed then calls it in <tr v-for="item in items | filteredList">. But it does not work also

Answer (score 0):

`items` only contains one "page" of the complete list, so if you want to search the whole data then you will have to apply the filter **before** the pagination.

How you do this depends on the source of the data - you could make a computed property `filteredItems` which applies the search filter, then change your table row to:

```
<tr v-for="item in filteredItems" :key="item.foo">
```

Comment: I've update the code using yours But still the same. Task 7 cannot be search.

In my code computed.

filteredList: function () {
            return this.items.filter(post => {
              return post.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            })
        },

Comment: Like I said, edit your question, but `items` is already paginated, so that's not going to change anything. The search must happen **before** the pagination.